# Hive doesn't pick up partition with the calculated partition key

Tags: hive, hiveql

My external table `auto1_tracking_events_ext`  is partitioned on a column `dt`.

First i execute:

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
```

When I run this query:

```
select count(*)
from auto1_tracking_events_ext
where dt = '2016-12-05';
```

It picks up the partition, creates maybe like 3 mappers and finishes in a couple of seconds.

However if i run this:

```
select count(*)
from auto1_tracking_events_ext
where dt = from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

It does **not** pick up the partition and starts 413 mappers and takes quite some time to calculate.

For the time of posting this question:

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
OK
2016-12-05
```

Why does Hive not pick up the partition?

UPDATE:

Passing date string as hiveconf parameter (as shown below) does **not** help either.

```
hive -hiveconf date_yesterday=$(date --date yesterday "+%Y-%m-%d")
hive> select count(*) from auto1_tracking_events_ext where dt = ${hiveconf:date_yesterday};
```

Comment: My guess on this is that Hive is calculating the date comparison for every record in the table before doing any filtering. You could try to change the where clause filter to dt=(select  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) to see if it calculates the date first. I am also not sure if you can have a select in a where clause in Hive, so you may need to inner join to it instead.

Comment: Yes. I thought of trying that, but unfortunately in my version of Hive subquries are not allowed. They appear in 0.13

Answer (score 0):

Your last query with passing hiveconf variable should work as well if first query works, because variables are being substituted first and only after that query is being executed. It is one possible bug, you did not quote the variable. Try this:

```
hive -hiveconf date_yesterday=$(date --date yesterday "+%Y-%m-%d")
hive> select count(*) from auto1_tracking_events_ext where dt = '${hiveconf:date_yesterday}'; --single quotes here
```

Without quotes it is resolved like this `where dt=2020-12-12` - this is wrong, it should be single quotes.

As for using `unix_timestamp()` - [the function is not deterministic and prevents proper query optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58081191/2700344).

Use `current_date` or `current_timestamp` instead:

```
select count(*)
from auto1_tracking_events_ext
where dt = date_sub(current_date,1);
```