# Calculate the Age from the DOB

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am using HiveQL and I need to calculate the age just by using the Date of birth column but the issue is `GetDate` doesn’t work however `Current_Date()` does. The example I am trying is

`datediff(yy,Dateofbirthcol,current_date()) As Age`.

The DOB column looks like `1988-12-14`.

Comment: Maybe you should add your entire request, this will help us

Answer (score 2):

Try one of the following option.

1. `floor(datediff(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())), Dateofbirthcol) / 365.25)`
2. `datediff(now(), Dateofbirthcol) / 365.25`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use unix_timestamp() because it is [non-deterministic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58081191/2700344). Use current_date:

```
 datediff(current_date, Dateofbirthcol) / 365.25
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thank you every one for all your help and I am sorry I will not be doing that next time